# Julia - Accessing Arrays after end of for loop

Tags: julia

I am trying to make array calculation with nested for loops.

When I am trying to access the arrays with println after the end of the nested for loops I get no results.

Does this have to do with global and local variables inside the for loops?

And if yes, how do I get access to the results of the iterations outside the nested for loops?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation says:](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/control-flow/#man-loops-1) *If the variable i has not been introduced in an other scope, in the for loop form, it is visible only inside of the for loop, and not afterwards.*

So you could define variable outside of `for` scope:

```
julia> function test()
     local i  # here I introduce i
     sum = 0 
     for i in 1:3
       sum+=i   
     end
     println("$i,$sum")
   end
test (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test()
3,6
```

Or you could use `while`.

Edit: changed according to Dan Getz's comment.

Comment: Using `local i` instead of `i = 0` may be nicer

Comment: I do not use a function. Just variables in the for loop.

Comment: Thanks @DanGetz! :)

Comment: @Lvassilopoulos it is useful to use functions if [performance is important](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/). It could to increase readability too. In case you insists to be in global level you could use `global i`

Comment: i am running another algorithm using nested for loops and the variables are accessible after the end of for loops. How can this be?